# Postgres - npm script to drop/add database

Tags: postgresql, npm, psql

I want to simplify my life and automate the process of adding/dropping my test db via an npm script, however I am running into issues.

**Attempt 1:**

```
"drop-db:local": "psql postgres \"drop database blog_db; create database blog_db; \\c blog_db; CREATE EXTENSION \"pgcrypto\";\""
```

After running this, I keep getting the following error

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "drop database blog_db; create database blog_db; \c "
```

**Attempt 2:**

changed
`psql postgres`
to
`psql -h localhost -U rm postgres`

So this opens the db in my terminal but that seems to ignore some stuff as mentioned in the msg below

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "drop database blog_db; create database blog_db; \c blog_db; CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;" ignored
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is a list of my db users

```
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 rm        | Superuser, Create DB                                       | {}
```

db version: psql (12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use -c or -f with your psql command.
As the psql help shows:

```
-c, --command=COMMAND    run only single command (SQL or internal) and exit
-f, --file=FILENAME      execute commands from file, then exit
```

As you are using multiple commands so it will be better of you use -f followed by a sql file name that has all the commands e.g your drop_create_db.sql file can have following code:

```
drop database blog_db; 
create database blog_db; 
\c blog_db; 
CREATE EXTENSION "pgcrypto";
```

And you may run this file by using the following command

```
"drop-db:local": psql -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432 -f /tmp/drop_create_db.sql
```

Comment: Thanks! The command that worked for me was ```"drop-db:local": "psql -U rm -d postgres -p 5432 -f sql/drop_create_db.sql"``` - different user and omitting the `/` before `sql` directory